# MapboxGL polygons are black colored if property missing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I am having issue with colors of the polygons. So i display polygones/areas in the map and i set for each color depending of their properties:

```
map.setPaintProperty("layerName", "fill-color", [
            "interpolate",
            ["linear"],
            ["get", key],
            range[0], colors[0],
            range[1], colors[1],
            range[2], colors[2],
        ]);
```

But some of these polygons just do not have the "key" property in them hence the map reads them like undefined/nullish  and sets default color to them a pure black. I need to change this black color to something else  but cant figure it out.

I tried to add default color after the ranges but it didnt work .  Also tried if i could do it via styling/css but its a canvas so seems that this is not an option.

```
map.setPaintProperty("layerName", "fill-color", [
            "interpolate",
            ["linear"],
            ["get", key],
            range[0], colors[0],
            range[1], colors[1],
            range[2], colors[2],
          defaultColor
        ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me :

```
//This will put color of white for the missing property 
map.setPaintProperty(
                    'layerName',
                    'fill-color',
                    ["case", ["==", ["get", key], null], "#ffffff", [
                        "interpolate",
                        ["linear"],
                        ["get", key],
                        range[0], colors[0],
                        range[1], colors[1],
                        range[2], colors[2],
                    ]]
                );
```

This works also for opacity:

```
map.setPaintProperty(
            'layerName',
            'fill-opacity',
            ["case", ["==", ["get", key], null], 0.1, 0.7]
        );
```

Comment: Awesome solution. These mapbox expressions get pretty complicated